# Persisting a user's selection in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to persist the selection of a field(in this case the "Event" field) in the django admin such that when the admin "save and add another", the selected value does not change. I'm not sure if this is the default django behaviour. Either way,I had the overide the form to do some custom filtering/error checking. I also do not want to touch the views/templates. My original plan was to save the selected value into the session and then retrieve it when the form inits but I could not find a way to pass a request object into the ScoreAdmin form.

Any suggestions as to what to do next?

What I have so far

```
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(ScoreForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)

    standard_events = Event.objects.filter(event_score_type='STD')
    event_widget = self.fields['event'].widget

    choices = []
    for element in standard_events:
        choices.append((element.id, element.name))
    event_widget.choices = choices

def clean_score(self):
    print self.request.session
    print(self.cleaned_data['event'])
    selected_event = Event.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data['event'])
    if(selected_event.max_score > selected_event.min_score):
        if self.cleaned_data['score'] < 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Negative")
        elif self.cleaned_data['score'] > selected_event.max_score:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Greater Than Best Possible Score of " + str(selected_event.max_score))
        elif self.cleaned_data['score'] < selected_event.min_score:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Less Than Worst Possible Score of " + str(selected_event.min_score))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['score']
    elif selected_event.max_score < selected_event.min_score:
        if self.cleaned_data['score'] < 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Negative")
        elif self.cleaned_data['score'] < selected_event.max_score:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Less Than Best Possible Score of " + str(selected_event.max_score))
        elif self.cleaned_data['score'] > selected_event.min_score:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Greater Than Worst Possible Score of " + str(selected_event.min_score))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['score']
    class Meta:
        model = Score


class ScoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ScoreForm
    pass
```

A screenshot

[image: I want to persist the 'Event' field in between additions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to override the value of the Event node in the form if there is a session variable that exists. Something like below but wrapped with an if. It's hard to get too specific without the model information, but that should give you the general idea.

```
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScoreForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # call the parent init
        self.initial['Event'] = self.get_my_session_var
```

Mostly from the information in this post:
[How to override field value display in Django admin change form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941971/how-to-override-field-value-display-in-django-admin-change-form)

Comment: I understand that part. What I don't understand is how to pass the request object from ScoreAdmin(extends admin.ModelAdmin) to its associated form object ScoreForm(extends form.ModelForm). I tried overriding the get_form method to no avail. Any suggestions?