# Override default display of Custom field in Django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a custom field which is defined as below:

```
class SeparatedValuesField(models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.token = kwargs.pop('token', ';')
    super(SeparatedValuesField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def to_python(self, value):
    if not value:
        return
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return value
    return value.split(self.token)

def get_db_prep_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
    if not value:
        return
    assert (isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, tuple))
    return self.token.join([unicode(s) for s in value])

def value_to_string(self, obj):
    value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
    print (value)
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value)
```

It allows me to submit a list of string, then concat it into a long string to save to database.

The problem is when I use the default admin site of the model to change an existing object, the `value_to_string` method is not called. So if I have in my db `some_str`, it will be displayed as `[u'some_str]` (which I believe is the default stringify behaviour of list). And when I save it to db, the value changed to `['usome_str]` literally. And when I load it again, it would be `[u'[u'some_str]]`, so on and so on.

I am looking for a way to change the display in the admin form of the field which use that custom field, so I can make it displays as `some_str` instead of `['usome_str]`

P/s: I'm using django 1.6.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I have found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11942954/3870344

Basically, we need to create the custom form, and in the form override the display value by calling: `self.initial['some_field'] = some_encoding_method(self.instance.some_field)`

Cheers!