# Django comma-separated field does not work well with admin site

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I wrote a custom field as shown below, following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/) (Django 3.0).
This field allows to store a list of comma-separated strings.

My problem is that `from_db_value` is called also when populating the form field in the admin site.

For example, suppose that the value in the database is `alpha,beta`, representing the Python list `['alpha', 'beta']`. If I want to change the model instance, the form is populated with the string `['alpha', 'beta']`.
This would not be terrible, but when I save the model instance (without touching this field), the new value becomes `["['alpha'", " 'beta']"]`! In other words, the input to the form field is then interpreted as a comma-separated list.

What's the correct way to handle this, in order to have a usable admin site?

```py
class CommaSepField(models.CharField):
    description = "A comma-separated list of strings"

    def __init__(self, separator=",", *args, **kwargs):
        self.separator = separator
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        # Only include kwarg if it's not the default
        if self.separator != ",":
            kwargs['separator'] = self.separator
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        print('here', value)
        if value is None:
            return value
        return value.split(self.separator)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            return value
        else:
            return value.split(self.separator)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        else:
            return self.separator.join(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. Create a custom model form as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36474714/2468842) and set the `initial` for the field to be the value in the database (e.g. `alpha,beta`) instead of the Python representation (e.g. `['alpha', 'beta']`).
2. Check in `to_python` whether the value string is already a representation of a list literal. If it is, then use it directly instead of splitting again.

```py
class CommaSepField(models.CharField):
    description = "A comma-separated list of strings"

    def __init__(self, separator=",", *args, **kwargs):
        self.separator = separator
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        # Only include kwarg if it's not the default
        if self.separator != ",":
            kwargs['separator'] = self.separator
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        return self.to_python(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            return value
        else:
            literal = _eval_from_string_if_literal_type(value, list)
            value = self.get_prep_value(literal) if literal is not None else value
            return value.split(self.separator)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        else:
            return self.separator.join(value)


def _eval_from_string_if_literal_type(string, literal_type):
    """Try to get a literal value from a string

    This is useful for the Django admin form, where you would receive as input the string
    representation of a literal, such as a dict or list.
    """
    if isinstance(string, str):
        try:
            result = ast.literal_eval(string)
            if isinstance(result, literal_type):
                return result
        except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
            pass

    return None
```