# Initialise filed value to null when page loads in Django Admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

The following code is in **models.py** it is registered in **admin.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None,help_text="The full official name of the customer.")
email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False, default=None,)
password = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True, default=None,)
name_short = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None,help_text="The commonly used (short) name of the customer.")
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default=None,help_text="The main country code of the customer.")
status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None, help_text="1-2-3 temporary-registered-qualified.")
sample = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None, help_text="1 if sample customer.")
reset_password_otp = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
reset_password_otp_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
reset_password_otp_duration = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
created = models.DateTimeField('created', default=timezone.now)
updated = models.DateTimeField('updated', default=timezone.now)
```

I want to initialise the password field to null when the admin page loads.

Comment: Does the password field contain the customer's password in plain text?

Comment: no it contains the hashed password.

Comment: A similar question answered the problem. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941971/how-to-override-field-value-display-in-django-admin-change-form?lq=1][1]